# How to have the scanner class take floats?

Tags: java

Some small code for example

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number");
float number = scan.nextFloat();
```

This wont compile, is this an issue of syntax?

Comment: `import java.util.Scanner;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import **java.util.Scanner** class. See below code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        float number = scan.nextFloat();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will compile,just check your imports.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Answer (score 1):

It does compile like @Shanu Gupta mentioned you need to have the right classes imported.

Here's a runable example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        float number = scan.nextFloat();
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```